# GreenDAO cannot access existed database after upgrading sqlcipher from 3.5.2 to 4.0.1

Tags: android, greendao, sqlcipher

I'm using `GreenDAO` with `SQLCipher`.
After I upgrade `SQLCipher` from 3.5.2 to 4.0.1, my app cannot access the old encrypted database.
I have already searched for a solution and found out that I need to run PRAGMA cipher_migrate in `postKey` of the `SQLiteDatabaseHook` to migrate my database. I tried like this, but nothing changes.:

```
    SQLiteDatabaseHook hook = new SQLiteDatabaseHook() {
        @Override
        public void preKey(SQLiteDatabase database) {

        }

        @Override
        public void postKey(SQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("PRAGMA key = '" + key + "';");
            database.execSQL("PRAGMA cipher_migrate;");
        }
    };
    Database db = new EncryptedDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("DB.db", key, null, hook));
    return new DaoMaster(db).newSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `"DB.db"` to `openOrCreateDatabase` when it wants a path. You want to do something like:

```
    File dbPathFile = new File(path);
    if (!dbPathFile.exists()) {
      dbPathFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
```

and then pass `path` where you passed `"DB.db"` in `openOrCreateDatabase`