# GreenDAO Cannot access existing database after upgrading sqlcipher from 3.5.4 to 4.2.0

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao, sqlcipher

I'm using GreenDAO with SQLCipher. After I upgrade SQLCipher from 3.5.4 to 4.2.0, my app cannot access the old encrypted database. I have already searched for a solution and found out that I need to run PRAGMA cipher_migrate in postKey of the SQLiteDatabaseHook to migrate my database. I tried the following, but it didn't fix it:

```
SQLiteDatabaseHook hook = new SQLiteDatabaseHook() {
@Override
public void preKey(net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase database) {}
@Override
public void postKey(net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase database) {
                SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);
                database.execSQL("PRAGMA key = '" + key + "';");
                database.execSQL("PRAGMA cipher_migrate;");
            }
        };
try {
            logger.d(TAG, "before openOrCreateDatabase");
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("DB.db", password, null, hook);
            logger.d(TAG, "before EncryptedDatabase");
            db = new EncryptedDatabase(sqLiteDatabase);
            logger.d(TAG, "DB session is encrypted");
            return new DaoMaster(db).newSession();
} catch (Exception e) {
```

I get this error:

```
No implementation found for void net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(java.lang.String, int) (tried Java_net_sqlcipher_database_SQLiteDatabase_dbopen and Java_net_sqlcipher_database_SQLiteDatabase_dbopen__Ljava_lang_String_2I)
Could not dispatch event: class com.*.LoginResponse to subscribing class class com..LoginViewModel
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(java.lang.String, int) (tried Java_net_sqlcipher_database_SQLiteDatabase_dbopen and Java_net_sqlcipher_database_SQLiteDatabase_dbopen__Ljava_lang_String_2I)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabaseInternal(SQLiteDatabase.java:3)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:10)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:7)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:5)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:3)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:3)
at com.elt.passsystem.infrastructure.di.modules.GreenDAOModule.provideDAO(GreenDAOModule.java:8)
at com.elt.passsystem.infrastructure.di.modules.GreenDAOModule_ProvideDAOFactory.get(GreenDAOModule_ProvideDAOFactory.java:3)
at com.elt.passsystem.infrastructure.di.modules.GreenDAOModule_ProvideDAOFactory.get(GreenDAOModule_ProvideDAOFactory.java:1)
```

Comment: this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785383/greendao-cannot-access-existed-database-after-upgrading-sqlcipher-from-3-5-2-to?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

do `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);` before you try to initialize the db itself

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example here:

https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/zetetic/tests/CipherMigrateTest.java

And also add SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(getApplicationContext()); in your Application class.